# How to find the maximum value of $a_1 \cos(w_1 t + \phi_1) + a_2 \cos(w_2 t + \phi_2)$?

Tags: trigonometry, maxima-minima

Let us define
$$f_1(t) = a_1 \cos(w_1 t + \phi_1)$$
and
$$f_2(t) = a_2 \cos(w_2 t + \phi_2).$$

The ratio of the periode length is rational, $\frac{\omega_1}{\omega_2} \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Finally, I want to find the maximum point $\left(t^*, f(t^*)\right)$, where $f(t) = f_1(t)+f_2(t)$.
I guess $t^*$ must be the function of $a_i$, $w_i$, and $\phi_i$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$, and want to observe the relation between $t^*$ and them.

I've already tried to solve the problem $$\max_t f(t)$$ using some formulas about trigonometric functions and differentiation, but I failed to find $t^*$.
Actually, I can find a value using some software (e.g. MATLAB) but I want to find $t^*$ into a closed form equation with respect to $a_i$'s, $w_i$'s and $\phi_i$'s.

Thanks to tell me some materials with respect to this issue or direction to do for the next step.

Comment: Hint: if $\frac{\omega_1}{\omega_2}$ is not rational, then $f_1+f_2$ is aperiodic...

Comment: Weird idea: first you could derive the sum, it is clear. Essentially $t$ will be given by an equation like $\sin \alpha + \sin c \alpha = 0$. It is unsolvable by high school trigonometrical identities. However... using $\sinh \alpha = -i \sin i \alpha$, you could transform it to a complex exponential equation, it will be still dirty, but it will be maybe solvable with [superlogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: @peterh I consider $w_i=2 \pi f_i$, where $f_i$ is very high rational value (actually I will treat it as a natural number, e.g., 900 MHz or 2.4 GHz).

Comment: I said the proportion of the periodic lengths! I can't understand, there is the formula in the first comment, $\frac{\omega_1}{\omega_2}$, what you can't understand in it? If you add two periodic functions, f.e. the first has a period length of 1, the second has, for example, $\sqrt{2}$, then the sum won't be periodic! But if $\omega_2$ is only $1.41$ times bigger than $\omega_1$, then they will be periodic (but the period length will be big, so you will have many local maxima!)

Comment: @peterh I do not consider a case in which $w_i$ is irrational, so I think there must be not irrational $\frac{w_1}{w_2}$ as well.

Comment: I thought a little bit. I think the superlogarithm-based solution will give you a closed formula, the Lambert Omega is not a beautiful function, but it can be calculated quickly with computers and so or so we can call it "closed form". This closed formula will likely show all the local minima, maxima and inflexion points, you will have somehow to find the absolute maxima from them.

Comment: @peterh I understood, there must be a lot of local minima, so the global optimal solution cannot be found. If so, is there no way to figure out the smallest value in the following case? ($f_1=900\times10^6$ and $f_2=2.4\times10^9$ and $w_i=2\pi f_i$, $a_i$'s are one, and $\phi_i$'s are zeros). The maximum value must be $2$ but the minimum value is a little bit larger than $-2$. Can't I find what exact value it is?

Comment: Then $\omega_2 = 2.666... \cdot \omega_1$, so 8 periods of $f_1$ will equal 3 periods of $f_2$. If the periods are fixed, you can simply calculate it with a computer, or even by hand (it will be harder).

Comment: Heyy, answerers reading your question have no idea, what is in your mind, they can see only your text! Write everything into the question what they might need. Good luck!